# showModalDialog arguments does not pass in WPF WebBrowser control

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

Where a url called via `showModalDialog`, in IE all work but in WebBowser-Control the page its appears, but apparently we do not receive the arguments.

Here is a demonstration of the problem, the first page is: ***Parent.html:***, the second page is ***NewForm.html***. In IE, the second page works well: `myDiv` contains the input. while in WebBowser-Control `myDiv` contains "type undefined".

***Parent.html:***,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>ParentPage</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p >Type text:</p> 
   <input id="myInput"/>
   <button onclick="callPrintNewForm()">showModalDialog</button>
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function callPrintNewForm() 
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        alert(x);
        var wnd;
        wnd = window.showModalDialog('NewForm.html', window, "dialogWidth:800px;dialogHeight:600px;help:no;resizable:yes;scrollbars=Yes")
    }
</script>
</html>
```

***NewForm.html:***,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DialogPage</title>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:window_onload();">
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var Wnd = null;
    Wnd = window.dialogArguments;

    var Data =Wnd.document.getElementById("myInput").value;

    function window_onload() {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerText = "Typed: " + Data;
    }
</script>  
</html>
```

work in IE but in WPF

```
<WebBrowser Source="S:\Tries\Parent.html" />
```

The way it looks arguments does not pass to the dialog page
According to what appears this is not supported, is there workarounds?

It's not my page and I have no choice

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @jurgemaister I edited the question, is it good?